# using typeahead-mvc-model in dynamically created Html.AutoCompleteFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

I'm using the typeahead [package](https://github.com/timdwilson/typeahead-mvc-model) from timdwilson. Unfortunately, I run into a problem when I place the `AutoCompleteFor` box in a for loop as the lambda expressions don't play nice with the `AutocompleteHelpers` class (in particular, the `Expression` evaluator.

Essentially, instead of `model => model.SelectedIngredeints[i]` I get `model => model.SelectedIngredients.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Recipes_Create_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).i)`

Is there anyway C# can evaluate `SelectedIngredients.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Recipes_Create_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).i` to simply `SelectedIngredients[i]`?

---

In case I'm not making myself clear, here are some screen shots...

Here it works no problem because `model => model.testInt` is already(?) evaluated or referenced.

[image]
[image]

---

**However, when I try to use my iterator, the below happens.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm timdwilson and I created the Twitter.Typeahead.MVC.Model NuGet package and typeahead-mvc-model GitHub repository you are having trouble with. After looking at your issue, I see that, indeed, the HTML that was generated for the `data-autocomplete-id-field` attribute for the input element by `AutocompleteFor` should have been `SelectedIngredients_0_` but instead was `SelectedIngredients.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Recipes_Create_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).i)`.

In other words, you were expecting this:

```html
<input class="form-control typeahead" data-autocomplete-id-field="SelectedIngredients_12_" data-autocomplete-url="/Recipes/GetIngredients" id="SelectedIngredientsNames_12_" name="SelectedIngredientsNames[12]" type="text" value="" />
```

But, instead, were getting this:

```html
<input class="form-control typeahead" data-autocomplete-id-field="SelectedIngredients.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_Recipes_Create_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).i)" data-autocomplete-url="/Recipes/GetIngredients" id="SelectedIngredientsNames_12_" name="SelectedIngredientsNames[12]" type="text" value="" />
```

Since the `data-autocomplete-id-field` is used to find this element on the page and  set it's value, the selected id was never being captured when a typeahead value was selected.

I fixed this by properly generating the HTML, the same way that the `valueExpression` is being generated.  This fix will appear in the [Twitter.Typeahead.MVC.Model version 1.0.6 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Typeahead.MVC.Model/) and it has already been checked in to the [typeahead-mvc-model GitHub repository](https://github.com/timdwilson/typeahead-mvc-model).

To fix this in your local copy, replace the AutocompleteHelpers class in the Controllers\HtmlHelpers folder (or wherever you moved it to) with the following code:

```cs
public static class HtmlHelpers {

    /// <summary>
    /// Extends MvcHtml to conditionaly display a value or empty string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be displayed if 'evaluation' is true</param>
    /// <param name="evaluation"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation) {
        return evaluation ? value : MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extends MvcHtml to conditionaly display one of two possible values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to be displayed if 'evaluation' is true</param>
    /// <param name="evaluation"></param>
    /// <param name="valueIfFalse">Value to be displayed if 'evaluation' is false</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, bool evaluation, MvcHtmlString valueIfFalse) {
        return evaluation ? value : valueIfFalse;
    }
}

public static class AutocompleteHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty1>> valueExpression,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty2>> idExpression, string actionName, string controllerName, bool requestFocus)
    {
        return CreateTextBoxForFromAutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(html, valueExpression, actionName, controllerName, requestFocus,
            idExpression.Body.ToString());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty1>> valueExpression,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty2>> idExpression, int index, string actionName, string controllerName, bool requestFocus)
    {
        // Get the fully qualified class name of the autocomplete id field
        string idFieldString = idExpression.Body.ToString();

        // handle if the id field is an array
        int loc_get_Item = idFieldString.IndexOf(".get_Item(");
        if (loc_get_Item > 0)
        {
            idFieldString = idFieldString.Substring(0, loc_get_Item);
            idFieldString += string.Format("_{0}_", index);
        }

        var textBoxFor = CreateTextBoxForFromAutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(html, valueExpression, actionName, controllerName, requestFocus, idFieldString);
        return textBoxFor;
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString CreateTextBoxForFromAutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty1, TProperty2>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty1>> valueExpression, string actionName, string controllerName, bool requestFocus, string idFieldString)
    {
        string autocompleteUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName,
                                                       null,
                                                       html.RouteCollection,
                                                       html.ViewContext.RequestContext,
                                                       includeImplicitMvcValues: true);
        string @class = "form-control typeahead" + (requestFocus ? " focus" : string.Empty);
        // We need to strip the 'model.' from the beginning
        int loc = idFieldString.IndexOf('.');
        // Also, replace the . with _ as this is done by MVC so the field name is js friendly
        string autocompleteIdField = idFieldString.Substring(loc + 1, idFieldString.Length - loc - 1).Replace('.', '_');
        var textBoxFor = html.TextBoxFor(valueExpression,
            new {data_autocomplete_url = autocompleteUrl, @class, data_autocomplete_id_field = autocompleteIdField});
        return textBoxFor;
    }
}
```

If this fix works for you, please accept this as the answer to your question.  If you have any additional questions or difficulties, please let me know.  Thanks Rory!

Comment: Something similar happens when de binding is to a nested property:
`<input id="ChangeData_OrganisationPlaceNumber" name="ChangeData.OrganisationPlaceNumber" type="hidden"...` 
`<input class="typeahead tt-hint" data-autocomplete-id-field="OrganisationPlaceNumber" ....`

Comment: I created a issue for it on github https://github.com/timdwilson/typeahead-mvc-model/issues/22